# How to construct a form in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to construct a form in a view ('Editor') in my MVC application but I am getting errors when the user presses the Submit button.  My form has a CKEditor control.

### My Editor View

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Edit"))
{
    <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="400" cols="100">
    @Model.Text
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

### My controller

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(FormCollection collection)
{
    string sText = collection[0].ToString();

    // save string from CKEditor

    return View("Editor");  //<-- I get the error here.
}
```

### Below is the error when returning from my controller.  If my return View() instead, I get the same error.

```
The view 'SubmitForm' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Edit/SubmitForm.aspx
~/Views/Edit/SubmitForm.ascx
~/Views/Shared/SubmitForm.aspx
~/Views/Shared/SubmitForm.ascx
~/Views/Edit/SubmitForm.cshtml
~/Views/Edit/SubmitForm.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/SubmitForm.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/SubmitForm.vbhtml
```

If I return my model instead 'return(MyModel)', I get a different error, 'System.NullReferenceException' at @Model.Text

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="400" cols="100">
@Model.Text
</textarea>
```

Comment: in which the directory is your  SubmitForm html file? ~/Views/??? ?

Comment: Can you tell me your controller name?

Comment: you return editor in controller so your view must be "Editor.cshtml".

Comment: The SubmitForm form is in the View folder.  The name of the controller is EditorController.

Comment: Per the recommendation below.  I deleted my view and removed my SubmitForm action to basically start over.  I right-clicked on my Editor() action selected Add View.  

I now no longer have the error.  I noticed that Editor() gets called when it displays the view and gets called again when I press the Save button.  Upon the Save, how do I get the data that user changed?  FormsCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your view is in wrong place and cannot be found during a runtime when submitform action is engaged! In a trace you can see location searched. The best way to do this automatically is right click on action and choose "add view" menu item. Other than that form looks ok!

Comment: I deleted my view and removed my SubmitForm action to basically start over.  I right-clicked on my Editor() action selected Add View.  

I now no longer have the error.   Thanks

Comment: I noticed that Editor() gets called when it displays the view and gets called again when I press the Save button.  Upon the Save, how do I get the data that user changed?  FormsCollection?